# Chrome extension content script - match pattern choice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that basically checks to see if certain elements exist on the current page.  I have a content script that contains all the functions to do the checking. Here is my manifest.json content_scripts section:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
]
```

...it seems pretty clumsy to have to set the wildcard matches to just be everything.  Is this the best practice?  I would assume most chrome extensions would want to always run against the current active tab regardless of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern means that content script will be injected into all pages:

```
"matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
```

You can find details in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns)